# Using several microcontrollers as nodes in a neural network

Tags: microcontroller, serial

I recently read an [EETimes article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1266579) about Google's neural network experiment, where they used several processor cores as nodes in a neural network. That made me wonder: could it be possible to replicate this with off-the-shelf microcontrollers?
I was thinking using 15 to 20 ATTinys or picaxe 10f200s and then interconnecting them via their serial communication lines.

Is this a viable concept?
If not, are there alternate ways of making this kind of neural network?

In other words, is this possible and if yes, how would I go about to make it? I'm new to this area of computer science, so I need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Reading your article it sounds to me like they used 16,000 processor cores and not "several computers". Do you know what the difference is? This question ought to be closed.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice that mistake. I'll change it ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the application, it would certainly be a possibility. The problem I foresee however, is that for an effective neural network, it needs to be trained via back propogation. Typical ATTiny is something like 20Mhz, whereas a computer is 2Ghz+. Training the neural network would require significantly more time due to the much lower processing speed. Which isn't to say it isn't possible, but you would have to carefully examine the application of your neural network before implementing it. It's also an Idea I've had for a while regarding robotics sensory, localization and path planning. Rather than programming a bunch of rules about how to move in an environment, have sensory input act as the inputs to neurons, which then teach the robot how best to interpret data to get to a destination.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! I was thinking keeping this simple. I would have LEDs connected to the output neurons and train them to output a specific flashing sequence.

Comment: Yeah. Something like that is definitely applicable at the microcontroller level, however a neural network isn't just the neurons and back propogation, it has to have something driving that back propogation to determine it's fitness. So if you're training a network to play a game for instance, the thing driving back propogation might be how long it's survived, how many points it's made etc. How would you drive that training in your case with LED's?

Comment: This is actually one of the reasons why I posted this inquiry. I'm not very experienced in this area of computer science and this project was going to be a first attempt at neural networks. Would you have any suggestions on how I would drive the network's training? Thanks!

Comment: Well it depends on how you envision the system working. Will you be in putting the sequence you want to the input neurons and have the neuron microcontroller learn how it controls its connected Leds? I think you'd have to have some other circuitry for feedback that you'll compare to your expected output.

Comment: That's pretty much it. I was thinking having a series of push buttons connected to the input neurons and then the network would have to match the button sequence with LED flashes.

Comment: Then I think you'd want to have an additional micro who's only job is to checks the input, stores it as a sequence, then checks that the output corresponds to your input sequence. It would need to be hooked up to both the buttons and the Leds to read them. Backpropogation could be driven by the time that sequence is correct, or percentage it got correct etc.

Comment: That sounds perfect. I now think I have a good basis to start building this. I'll keep you posted on the progress of the project and hopefully it'll be a success. Thanks again for your help! :-)

Comment: If I've answered your question adequately, it's best to accept the answer, as it closes the question and removes it from the unanswered section.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! I clicked the check mark.